# Progress 4GL - update

Tags: progress-4gl, webspeed

how can I check if update was successful when I run this For Each

FOR EACH products
WHERE products.name = "ProductsName":
update price = 1000.
END.

Sometimes this For Each is ok, but sometimes when record is lock it doesn't work. I need run this For Each via WebSpeed and return true when For Each is successful or false when not. How can I get this result?

Answer (score 0):

You should add more details to your request, but try this it might help get you started:

```
procedure update_items:
   define output parameter records_read as integer no-undo.
   define output parameter records_updated as integer no-undo.
   define output parameter records_locked as integer no-undo.
   define buffer item for item.
   define buffer item_update for item.
   define variable retry_count as integer no-undo.

   for each item no-lock:
      accumulate 1 (total).
      records_read = (accum total 1).
      
      retry_count = 0.
      repeat for item_update:
         find item_update exclusive-lock 
         where rowid(item_update) = rowid(item)
         no-wait no-error.
         if locked item_update then do:
            if retry_count > 5 then do:
               records_locked = records_locked + 1.
               leave.
            end.

            retry_count = retry_count + 1.
            do on endkey undo, leave:
               pause 3 no-message.
            end.
            undo, next.
         end.
         
         if not available item_update then do:
            /*If that matters you can code for it too*/
            leave.
         end.
         
         item_update.Price = 1000.         
         
         release item_update.
         
         records_updated = records_updated + 1.
         
         leave.
      end.      
   end.
end.

define variable items_read as integer no-undo.
define variable items_updated as integer no-undo.
define variable items_locked as integer no-undo.

run update_items(output items_read,
                 output items_updated,
                 output items_locked).

display items_read items_updated items_locked with side-labels 1 col.
```